# Disable element being clicked while data is being fetched in a server side blazor component

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to achieve something that in other rich UI frameworks it's pretty simple but I haven't understand the Blazor way. I'm trying to click a button, that onclick event fetches some data, and it takes some seconds. I just want to disable the button while this occurs. Im trying with a isLoading flag. but I cant make it render when this flag changes.
code:
Component.razor

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" disabled="@IsLoading" type="button" @onclick="Search">Search</button>
```

Component.razor.cs

```
public void Search() 
    {
        IsLoading = true;
        StateHasChanged();
        
        myVar = MyService.Search(); // here occurs the long fetching
        
        IsLoading = false;
    }
```

I have tried wrapping StateHasChanged(); in a invoke async and awaiting it.without success.
in the UI what i see that it does not update. i know the disable = @isloading interpolation works because if i initialized as true, it works properly. but i can make it change while the fech

Comment: Out of curiosity, add a `await Task.Delay(100)` just before the call to your `MyService.Search();`method.

Comment: for soem reasont it works, and it works just with that I tried to switch the service method to be asyn returning a task aaaand didn't work. but the delay does

Comment: Yeah, its because you are running code on the UI thread then spinning off to a background thread for processing. Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/rendering?view=aspnetcore-5.0#when-to-call-statehaschanged